# How create loopback interfaces in Linux permanently

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, amazon-web-services, loopback

I aim to create 2 loopback interfaces and have them saved permanently in *EC2 instance* on *AWS Linux Ubuntu based*.
I did the following in `/ect/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo lo:1 lo:2
iface lo inet loopback

iface lo:1 inet static
        address 127.0.0.1
        netmask 255.255.255.240
        network 127.0.0.0

iface lo:2 inet static
        address 127.0.0.2
        netmask 255.255.255.240
        network 127.0.0.0
```

When I restard the machine, I got nothing in `ifconfig` only the interfaces which are already configured when I installed the operating system.

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 172.2.1.10  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 172.2.1.15
        inet6 2600:1f14:8df:c16:b320:cc3f:ad7a:e26  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::843:d4ff:feb2:a872  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:43:d4:b2:a8:72  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 503  bytes 61839 (61.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 545  bytes 74423 (74.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 124  bytes 9720 (9.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 124  bytes 9720 (9.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Do a `ip addr show dev lo` and see if the additional IP addresses are there.

Comment: @LawrenceC there is only one which is shown in the `ifconfig`, the others are not shown.

Comment: The interesting question here is **why** do you think you need two loopback interfaces? If you want to assign multiple addresses to the loopback interface, you can do that on `lo` (which is created by default), and what is actually what the syntax `lo:1` and `lo:2` means. I can't think of any situation where multiple loopback interfaces would be needed.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to find a solution. It turns out the Ubuntu Server 18 has some other configuration for such purposes. I decided to go with version 16, and the configuration is working.